# SqlBulkCopy adding a variable to an Excel inport ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008

I have a `SqlBulkCopy` function that imports an Excel sheet. It works fine, except I would like to add a variable/constant value to the database table that does not exist in the Excel spreadsheet. Everything I have tried does not work.

I have been trying to add the variable `MyUser`, I keep getting the same error `OleDBException Was Unhandled`. The 2 lines that are commented out were the last 2 attempts I made. I am using asp.net 4.0, VS2010, SQL Server 2008.

```
Dim excelConnectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & MyFile & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;"""

Using connection As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString)

        Dim MyUser As String = UCase(My.User.Name)

        Dim command As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("Select MA_Code FROM [" & cboSheet.Text & "$]", connection)
        'Dim command As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("Select MA_Code, " & MyUser & " as MyUser FROM [" & cboSheet.Text & "$]", connection)
        'Dim command As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("Select MA_Code, " + MyUser + " as MyUser FROM [" & cboSheet.Text & "$]", connection)
        connection.Open()

        Using dr As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()

            Dim BKcn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
            BKcn.ConnectionString = My.Settings.MyConnection
            BKcn.Open()
            Try
                Using bulkCopy As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy(BKcn)
                    bulkCopy.BatchSize = 500
                    bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 3000
                    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = cboSheet.Text

                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("MA_Code", "MA_Code")
                    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dr)
                End Using
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add single quotes around the variable. I expect value of MyUser is being as though you were asking for a column with hat name:

If he userName is Bob, The SQL - after Concatenation would look like this, and there is no Bob Column:
`Dim command As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("Select MA_Code, Bob as MyUser FROM [" & cboSheet.Text & "$]", connection)`

you want it to look like this:

`Dim command As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("Select MA_Code, 'Bob' as MyUser FROM [" & cboSheet.Text & "$]", connection)`

Try this in your code

`Dim command As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("Select MA_Code, '" & MyUser & "' as MyUser FROM [" & cboSheet.Text & "$]", connection)`

Brian